# proof that a set of all bounded real valued functions is complete.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to understand the proof below. I know that a set A is complete if all Cauchy sequences converges in A.

I don't understand 7th line of the proof. Why do we consider particular $x_0 \in X$ and what is it saying when it says $(f_n(x_0))$ is a real Cauchy sequence?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward if you're familiar with what a Cauchy Sequence is already. In this case, it's a Cauchy Sequence of real numbers, which is nothing more than a convergent sequence of real numbers. It dictates what the value of $f$ should be at a point $x_0 \in X$. Since we want to determine the limiting function $f$, we wish to determine the value of $f$ on any $x_0 \in X$; this is exactly what it means to determine a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A priori you dont know that $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to a limit, that is $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ converges, but because of the hypothesis, that is $sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \epsilon $, fixing an $x$ you have that the sequence $(f_n(x))_n$ is a CAUCHY sequence in the REAL numbers ($|f_n(x_0) - f_m(x_0)| < \epsilon$ and this are real numbers, not functions), its not anymore a sequence of functions, and thus it converges. (Im assuming you already know that the reals are complete). Now you have the natural definition $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ for all $x \in X$. The rest of the proof is showing that this limiting function is again in $B(X)$